# Symfony2 bootstrap.php.cache tries to include a non-existent file

Tags: php, symfony, caching, apc

we have a Symfony 2.6.8 application, we randomly get this weird error log:

> [Thu Jun 11 12:29:14 2015] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] PHP Fatal error:   require(): Failed opening required 'aab' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /data/apps/front/1.1.1/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2752

The line 2752 of `bootstrap.php.cache` is:

```
if ($file = $this->findFile($class)) {
    require $file; // line 2752
    return true;
}
```

The `findFile()` method is:

```
public function findFile($class)
{
    if (false === $file = apc_fetch($this->prefix.$class))
    {
        apc_store($this->prefix.$class, $file = $this->decorated->findFile($class));
    }
}
```

Additional configuration informations, we are using:

- Symfony 2.6.8
- PHP 5.4.41
- APC 3.1.13

I don't understand what is this `aab` file that is requested. We are using an APC autoloader, so I am suspecting that APC has corrupted entries because
when restarting Apache2, the application works  as excepted. I can't debug when the application is in this state because we use `apc.stat = 0` so the php files are not reloaded at each request. Modifying the bootstrap doesn't work.

Perhaps our APC settings are not adapted:

```
apc.cache_by_default => On => On
apc.canonicalize => On => On
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => Off => Off
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.file_md5 => Off => Off
apc.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
apc.filters => no value => no value
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.include_once_override => Off => Off
apc.lazy_classes => Off => Off
apc.lazy_functions => Off => Off
apc.max_file_size => 1M => 1M
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.num_files_hint => 1000 => 1000
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.report_autofilter => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867 => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867_freq => 0 => 0
apc.rfc1867_name => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix => upload_ => upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.serializer => default => default
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 128M => 128M
apc.shm_strings_buffer => 4M => 4M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.stat => Off => Off
apc.stat_ctime => Off => Off
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.user_entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.user_ttl => 0 => 0
apc.write_lock => On => On
```

Any hint would be welcome!

Comment: Have you tried to regenerate the bootstrap via the console?

Comment: What version of PHP? Have you considered using opcache instead?

Comment: Additional informations added. ;) Well opcache seems for PHP 5.5 only.

Comment: @Med No, but restarting Apache seems to fix the problem temporarily...

Comment: Maybe this could bring you some more information:

`if ($file = $this->findFile($class)) {
    if (!file_exists($file) {
        xdebug_print_function_stack();
    }
    require $file; // line 2752
    return true;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this question which is exactly the same issue: ["Call to undefined method" after apache reload using apc opcode cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105077/call-to-undefined-method-after-apache-reload-using-apc-opcode-cache#comment54011525_27105077).

The bug comes from the Apache2 reload for the log rotate.

Removing the `ApcAutoloder` solved the issue.