# PHP Opcode cache locking Apache . Maybe Symfony2 - Doctrine2 related

Tags: php, apache, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I developped about 10 different websites, hosted on a single server with spec mentionned below.

**Story**:

Everything was running fine, until I decided to integrate a PHP Opcode cache into the system.
I first tried with APC, but the same problem appeared with Xcache, so i don't think it is related to the cache program itself.

The system remain stable for a period, varying from a day to a week, and crashes at various hours, but mainly at night around 23h-05h.
If I restart the httpd service, the system is stable again, during the same period (1 day to 1 week), and crashes again etc...

**Bug Report**:

Here is a report of my httpd global log during the last crash:

```
[Thu Feb 18 20:00:11.270997 2016] [core:notice] [pid 24956:tid 139940499228480] AH00052: child pid 4522 exit signal Aborted (6)
httpd: hostip.c:693: Curl_resolv_unlock: Assertion `dns && (dns->inuse>0)' failed.
[Thu Feb 18 20:08:38.793218 2016] [core:notice] [pid 24956:tid 139940499228480] AH00052: child pid 6246 exit signal Aborted (6)
httpd: hostip.c:693: Curl_resolv_unlock: Assertion `dns && (dns->inuse>0)' failed.
[Thu Feb 18 22:12:33.576308 2016] [core:notice] [pid 24956:tid 139940499228480] AH00052: child pid 8362 exit signal Aborted (6)
httpd: hostip.c:693: Curl_resolv_unlock: Assertion `dns && (dns->inuse>0)' failed.
[Thu Feb 18 22:40:07.297428 2016] [core:notice] [pid 24956:tid 139940499228480] AH00052: child pid 10224 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Thu Feb 18 23:00:40.526867 2016] [core:warn] [pid 24956:tid 139940499228480] AH00045: child process 10846 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
...
```

Note that the server became blocked around 22:41:xx . I restarted the server at 23:00:xx, which is related to the last line posted here.

It could be be related to curl, I'm using it a lot, specialy PHP curl_multi, in order to speed my API calls by launching them simultaneously. 
But the same error happens also without any PHP opcode cache installed (or disabled), but it does not crash the server down.

**Server State:**

When a "crash" occurs, the system can still serve any txt, image etc... file, but it can not serve any PHP file.
The server is locked, and when taking a look at the "Apache Server Status", there is maybe a hundred request in a "W" state, increasing with each incoming request.

**Cache Implementation:**

As stated above, I tried using APC and xCache, but both of them produced the same problem.
My PHP is a compiled version (that I did not compiled myself). 
There is a Varnish cache above all the websites, only caching a few time-hungry pages.
I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine2, with a link between Doctrine2 and  xcache/apc via a Symfony2 config:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: prod
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver: xcache
        result_cache_driver: xcache
        query_cache_driver: xcache
```

It seems to allow Doctrine2 to cache entity object and produce way better performances (only enabling cache was not enough for Doctrine2)

**Specifications**:

```
- Debian 7.8
- Apache 2.4.12
- Mysql 
- PHP 5.4.38 (compiled version)
- Varnish
- Symfony 2.4.x
```

Any hint or help will be greatly welcomed, as I've been looking for a solution for months, and running a PHP-Symfony2 website is alot slower without any opcode cache

Comment: What autoloader do you use in your app.php file ?

Comment: I use "ApcClassLoader" with a try catch, so when using xcache i guess it fallback to the default " $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache'; "

Comment: Check out this: may be it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780761/symfony2-bootstrap-php-cache-tries-to-include-a-non-existent-file

Comment: Unfortunately no, because my problem is not tied to APC, as the exact same problem occured with xcache, without any specific autoloader

Comment: What is the value of `%kernel.debug%`?

Comment: "prod". I edited my main post with this information

Comment: What version is cURL?  And is PHP running as CGI, FPM, Apache Module?

Comment: cUrl: version 7.26.0 . As for cgi/fpm or apache module, i can't tell for sure. My server API is "Apache 2.0 Handler" , which might mean it's an apache module ?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any specific cron jobs that are running around the time the server crashes?

In any case, if you are seeing `Curl_resolv_unlock: Assertion 'dns && (dns->inuse>0)' failed` in the logs, this means you have a "debug build" of libcurl active in PHP which is not good.

Your comment mentioned PHP says Apache 2.0 Handler, so it is running as an Apache module.

When that debug assertion hits in libcurl, it causes the process (PHP) to terminate.  Basically what I think is happening is that your PHP process for Apache (which handles all PHP requests) is dying.  This is why you can still serve static resources but PHP processes keep stacking up.

cURL 7.26.0 is fairly old (May 2012).  I'd suggest installing a newer version of libcurl, and then recompiling PHP with it and make sure cURL is not a debug build and see if this helps.

Comment: The thing is that the server does not crash without opcode cache, but the same error appears in the log, so I just don't understand why the cache could break something with cUrl. I will try to update cUrl and use a non debugg version as you suggest, I'll let you know if it helps. As a last solution, I think we are gonna reinstall the whole stack, with up-to-date php/cUrl and apache version

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you don't see PHP totally crash without any Opcache enabled (it could be that Apache reloads the PHP module and you don't see any effect), but maybe since the caches involve the use of shared memory, problems arise when PHP crashes without freeing up or releasing that memory.

Answer (score 2):

> My server API is "Apache 2.0 Handler"

You should *definitely* check out if a simillar behavior occurs under PHP-FPM. Apache SAPI means it's not separated from httpd's memory space as using FPM pool process.

I suspect you encounter on some kind of memory leak that cannot be easily traced. Changing to FPM will let you also to automatically restart responder after some time (requests amount) which is far more elegant and flexible than croning and checking if process works well.

Honestly, it's been some time since I had seen PHP connected by Apache SAPI. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't suggest you exact solution but i can suggest you a `trick` to solve your problem with workaround and suggest `debug` ideas

**A trick:** you can lunch a monitoring `cronjob` which will each 5-10m request through curl one of your websites and if he got negative response or request timeout expired(set it to some big number like 30sec or 1min) you will restart your `httpd` server + you can clean your `cache` then restart

**Debug:** to debug your problem you can start with `memory monitoring`. I guess root of problem is that during your errors your system memory leaking which making your `httpd` server to crash, which means you have to debug and handle your `curl` errors with `try/catch` etc ...

Comment: I already implemented a trick similar to the one you suggested a few days ago, but thanks for pointing this anyway :-) . For the debug part, i already tried to test that kind of memory leak, but it seems the CPU is overloaded more than the memory. Anyway, it's not any solution for me unfortunately, as it did not help finding the root of the problem

Answer (score 0):

So i have this cron php script that use pthreads and curl and i did get.

> php: hostip.c:693: Curl_resolv_unlock: Assertion `dns &&
>   (dns->inuse>0)' failed.

so i'm not sure but in curl you have this option

> **CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE**  TRUE to use a global DNS cache. This
>   option is not thread-safe and is enabled by default.

Change this to **FALSE**, I can't get that error for the moment even if i run a lot of thread calling a lot of URLs to the same place... this error did not start to show up until i did have a lot request in a rapid sequence.